# Как примонтировать битую флешку в линукс?

Tags: linux, bash

Привет всем!
Нашёл флешку на улице, KDE её монтировать отказался, Gparted её не видет.
Но... lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0c76:0005 JMTek, LLC. Transcend Flash disk
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 020: ID 0bda:571c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 040b:2014 Weltrend Semiconductor 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg

```
[138084.643151] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[138134.917523] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[138135.068546] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0c76, idProduct=0005
[138135.068554] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[138135.068558] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Mass Storage
[138135.068561] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: GENERIC 
[138135.068898] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[138135.069710] scsi15 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
```

То есть получается флешка аппаратно здоровая? 
Что с ней дальше делать, как привести в рабочее состояние?

P.S.

Я выводил `dmesg | grep usb` поэтому  не все выдало:

```
[138136.086431] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[138136.086960] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[138136.091619] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Но система совсем не видит [sdb], ну никак.

Нашел статью http://rlab.ru/doc/repair_usb_flash_linux.html не помогло.

Дополнил.

@alexanderbarakin
`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` не дает никакого эффекта, т.е. сразу выскакивает приглашение командной строки.....

```
echo -e 'o\nn\n\n\n\n\nw' | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
fdisk: невозможно открыть/dev/sdb: Носитель не найден
```

> похороните её с честью, в мусорном ведре.

Так и сделал!!!
Спасибо всем.

Comment: после такого http://habrahabr.ru/post/251451/ я бы не рисковал втыкать флешки, если я их не знаю.

раз она определяется - смотрите дальше, какое там будет имя (в Вашем логе этого нет).

Comment: @KoVadim: да-да, вспомнил эту историю ))

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду [sdb]?
`[138136.086431] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2`
`[138136.086960] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0`
`[138136.091619] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk`
Я уже все перепробовал все:
`sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/lfs`

Comment: @NatanTalifero, добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос вывод команды `$ ls -l /dev/sd*`, выполненной после того, как подключите устройство (на всякий случай выполняйте не сразу же после подключения, а спустя хотя бы секунд 5-10).

Comment: Все правильно! Без флешки:



`brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 авг.  30 12:04 /dev/sda`

`brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 авг.  26 20:21 /dev/sda1`

С ней родимой :)

`brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 авг.  26 20:21 /dev/sda1`

`brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 авг.  30 20:39 /dev/sdb`

Comment: @NatanTalifero, форматированная информация в комментариях практически нечитабельно. именно поэтому я и попросил вас дополнить ею ответ. // но, раз файл блочного устройства появляется, приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`. кстати, чтобы я получил уведомление о вашем ответе в комментарии, упомяните меня примерно так: `@alexanderbarakin`.

Comment: @NatanTalifero, я дополнил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если в кольцевом буфере *linux*-а (который можно просмотреть с помощью программы `dmesg`) больше ничего не появилось, значит, само блочное устройство (*usb-storage*) — неработоспособно.

а микросхема usb-контроллера, «рассказывающая»: «есть у меня блочное устройство!», — искренне заблуждается.

похороните её с честью, в мусорном ведре.

---

**обновлено**

раз файл блочного устройства всё-таки появляется, попробуйте создать на нём *dos partition table* и один раздел. например, так:

```
$ echo -e 'o\nn\n\n\n\n\nw' | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
$ sync
```

если после этого в каталоге не появится файл блочного устройства `/dev/sdb1`, дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос полным выводом приведённой команды (начинающейся с `echo`).

а если файл `/dev/sdb1` появился, то можно попробовать создать на нём файловую систему:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, у меня не хватает кармы написать комментарий, поэтому пишу как ответ. Мои извинения!

Вообще во флешке (во флеш-стике) находится две микросхемы: одна -- собственно сама микросхема флеш-памяти, а другая -- микроконтроллер.

Микроконтроллер имеет два интерфейса. Первый интерфейс -- USB, через него идет обмен с компом. Второй интерфейс работает с микросхемой памяти.

В двух словах -- что происходит при подключении флешки:

Комп видит, что к разъёму USB что-то "подцепилось". Компу нужно выяснить -- что "это" из себя представляет. Это устройство передачи данных по прерыванию типа мышки, клавы. Или это устройство, работающее в реальном времени (звуковые колонки). Или это устройство массива данных? Для всех этих типов устройств комп должен установить (подобрать) соответствующий протокол обмена. В процессе определения типа устройства комп общается с микроконтроллером, запрашивает у него идентификаторы, дескрипторы и другую служебную информацию.

После того как комп "поймёт", что подключенное устройство является устройством массива памяти, он должен определить такие параметры как сколько разделов (выражаясь по-Линуксовому, или сколько дисков -- выражаясь по-Виндовому) имеет устройство. Комп должен определить размеры разделов, начальный и конечный их адреса. Далее компу нужно знать какой тип файловой системы "накатан" на тот или иной раздел. Понятно, что эти данные микроконтроллер флешки не знает, да и не надо ему это знать! Сегодня эта флешка имеет один раздел, отформатированный в FAT32, а завтра продвинутый пользователь создаст на ней два раздела и "накатает" на них ext2.

Таким образом, на этом этапе комп должен получать информацию непосредственно из микросхемы флешь-памяти. А если она "убитая", то есть уже выработала свой ресурс, то микроконтроллер будет читать из нее мусор, а не достоверную информацию. Скорее всего процесс вычитывания информации из памяти "обломиться" по несовпадению контрольной суммы. А это значит, что микроконтроллер будет считать, что считывание из памяти было неудачно. Поэтому ничего полезного или значимого он не сможет "сказать" компу. Соответственно, и комп в свою очередь не сможет ничего определенного сказать пользователю относительно разделов и файловых систем.

Надеюсь, теперь Вам будет понятно, что и как происходит при подключении флешки, и что следует делать, если что-то не получается.

К стати, поскольку флешки изготовляются на базе разных микроконтроллеров, с разной тактовой частотой, а в самих микроконтроллерах записаны абсолютно разные микропрограммы, то становится понятно, почему флешки так сильно различаются по своему быстродействию.